# What is the location link to which I have to add only the location code to get the map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox

I have a table contains the locations codes ( that we get from google map by right click then choose "What is here")
I have to add this locations code as a substitution variable. but I do not know what is the link that I have to add to which my location code TO GET ONLY THE MAP not the entire page of Google map ..
e.g

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=#LOCATIONS#
```

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.052013,55.270243
THAT LINK gives the entire page of Google, but I need only the map to show up in Facny Box.

Answer (score 0):

This short tutorial should help you: [How to integrate Fancybox and Google Maps](http://webdesignandsuch.com/integrate-fancybox-with-google-maps/)

The map to show is inside an hidden div like this:

```
<div style="display:none; *margin-left:-9999px; *height:0px; *position:relative; *top:-500px; *display:block ">
    <div id="mapBox" >
        <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.052907,55.2702&amp;num=1&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=25.052013,55.270243&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.052907,55.2702&amp;num=1&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=25.052013,55.270243&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
    </div>
</div>
```

I suppose that the link, you are looking for, is this one inside the iframe. You can get the iframe after clicking the link with a chain as icon, that is placed at the top left of the page that you open with http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.052013,55.270243

Answer (score 0):

You may also check my post about how to open google maps in fancybox the easy way [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/ef30ef118ec3ebb4/)